# doubly_linked list Insert after a certain node ends in loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

Trying to learn Data Structures in Python, implementing doubly linked list. When I am trying to insert a new element after an element, it is ending up in a continuous loop. Please try to explain where I am going wrong and why is it ending it continuous loop.

I am posting my entire code here but the issue is at insertAt. Please help.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None

class Double_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
    def beginning(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
        else:
            temp = self.head
            node.next = temp
            temp.prev = node

    def addelement(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        if not self.head:
            self.beginning(data)
            return
        temp = self.head
        last = temp
        while temp.next:
            temp = temp.next
        temp.next = node
        node.prev = temp
    
    def ending(self, data):
        self.addelement(data)

    def insertAt(self, data, after=None):
        node = Node(data)
        temp = self.head
        while temp and after:           
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            last = temp
            temp = temp.next
            if last.data == after:
                last.next = node
                node.prev = last
                node.next = temp
                temp.prev = node
            

    def remove(self,data):
        temp = self.head
        while temp:
            if temp.data == data:
                break
            last = temp
            temp =temp.next
        last.next = temp.next
        temp.next.prev = last

    def printll(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp:
            print (temp.data, end=" ")
            temp = temp.next

obj = Double_list()
obj.beginning(1)
obj.addelement(2)
obj.ending(3)
obj.insertAt(data=4,after=1)
obj.remove(2)
obj.printll()
```

Comment: Why does your `insertAt` have a `before` parameter? It is never used... Please also provide the (minimal) driver code with which the problem is reproduced.

Comment: Is `insertAt` intended to insert multiple nodes when `after` occurs multiple times in the list?

Comment: Hi @trincot
Thanks for your response.
No. It is intended to add single element only. I have modified the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `insertAt` is intended to insert at most *one* node, you should exit the loop as soon as it has been added (`break`). Because this doesn't happen in your code, there is a risk that the *same* node is added a second time (when `after` occurs a second time), and this will lead to an inconsistently linked list.

Some other issues in that method:

- you should protect your algorithm from accessing `temp.prev` when `temp` happens to be `None`.
- The while loop condition should not have anything about `after`.
- The function doesn't use `before`, so this shouldn't be a parameter.
- If the `after` value is not found in the list, no node should be inserted, and thus it is better to only create the node when `after` has been found.

So:

```
    def insertAt(self, data, after=None): # No `before`
        temp = self.head
        while temp:  # No condition on `after`
            last = temp
            temp = temp.next
            if last.data == after:
                node = Node(data)  # <-- moved!
                last.next = node
                node.prev = last
                node.next = temp
                if temp:  # avoid error
                    temp.prev = node
                break  # stop looking further
```

Another remark: the `beginning` method should *always* do `self.head = node` even if the list already had nodes.